# Migrate my app from WatchOS1 to WatchOS2

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I'm migrating my application from WatchOS1 to WatchOS2. I was sharing data on watch OS1 using app group with the help of core data, so I want the same functionality on watch OS2. How can I achieve this same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. You can't use app group to share data between watchkit extension and it's companion App. You have to use `WatchConnectivity` to share data for watch OS2. And this is totally different approach with app group.

WatchOS2 App extension is installed on watch itself not like watch OS1 App extension was installed on iPhone. So shared app group on watchOS2 is used to share data between other watch os2 apps that are provided by same vendor.